# TortoiseSVN import add-ins for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, svn, tortoisesvn

I have installed TortoiseSVN on my computer and on my SQL server, I have some databases for which I don't have solutions. Instead all of my **stored procedures, views, etc.** are stored on the local domain server. Now I want to import all of my stored procedures, views, and functions into my **SVN repository**.

To import, I copy each SP, views, etc. into a local folder and then import them into my SVN repository. Since it was a big process, I started searching for a TortoiseSVN plugin for SQL Server 2008. I found two reliable sources ([**Agent SVN**](http://www.zeusedit.com/agent/) or [**RedGate**](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/)) but they are not free.

I was trying to add the **TortoiseSVN command-line** to SSMS External Tools as explained here: [SVN add-in for SSMS](http://jrummell.com/sql-server-management-studio-and-tortoisesvn)

For example, to import a SQL solution into an SVN repository, I have to use:

```
Title: SVN Import
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe
Arguments: /Command:import /path:”$(SolutionDir)”
Initial directory: $(SolutionDir)
```

It works fine if I have an SSMS  solution, But as I said, I don't have a solution. I just have it like this:

```
-Object Explorer (Domain server)
   --Databases (Folder)
     --- My Database (sub folder)
      ----Tables (sub sub folder)
      ----Views (sub sub folder)
      ----Programmability (sub sub folder)
        ----- Stored Procedures (sub sub sub folder) etc.
```

**Question:**  Is there a way where I can just select my stored procedures and then 
`SVN Import`, so that it imports all of those stored procedures into my SVN repository?
For example, suppose I want to import all of my stored procedures, then I click on the **Stored Procedures** folder and from the **`Tools` bar**, I select **SVN Import**, which should copy all of the stored procedures in that folder into my SVN repository.

Answer (score 1):

I found this post which may help:
[SMO? Scripting of all SQL stored procedures with if exists drop then create and no sp_executesql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381397/smo-scripting-of-all-sql-stored-procedures-with-if-exists-drop-then-create-and)

The answer links to a powershell script that does most of what you need, which you can configure as a "tool" in SSMS. However, because it doesn't seem possible to pass in the server and database as variables, you'll have to hard code these, or prompt for them in your code.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, because i am not familiar with power shell or SMO.

Comment: I'm no expert myself. Your best bet is if you Google for "how to get started with powershell" and see if you can run the script that is linked off the answer I referenced above.